# Selenium, stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document (Python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#import requests



options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#All are optional
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument("--disable-Advertisement")
options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

driver= webdriver.Chrome(options=options)


#driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
#driver.implicitly_wait(10)

path = "https://youtube.com"
driver.get(path)

#xpath for search box
x_path_for_box = "/html/body/ytd-app/div[1]/div/ytd-masthead/div[4]/div[2]/ytd-searchbox/form/div[1]/div[1]/input"
searching_point_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value=x_path_for_box)

#user manual input
search_word = input("Enter the search keyword: ")
searching_point_box.send_keys(search_word)

#xpath for search button
x_path_search_button= "/html/body/ytd-app/div[1]/div/ytd-masthead/div[4]/div[2]/ytd-searchbox/button"
searchButton = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value=x_path_search_button)
searchButton.click()

new_path ="https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + search_word
driver.get(new_path)


SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 3
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")

item_count = 180

while True:
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.documentElement.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")

    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
    


links = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, value = "a")


substring = "watch?v="

list_of_links = []
for link in links:
    href = link.get_attribute("href")
    list_of_links.append(href)

    
    
filtered_links = []

for i in list_of_links:
    if substring in i and i != "None":
        filtered_links.append(i)
        print(i)
```

My program is supposed  to scrape urls only with pattern "watch?=v", but I get this error, I am not pretty sure what shall I change, It gets every link based on topic you type in but it doesnt want to filter it out, this message is showing up:
Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
(Session info: chrome=111.0.5563.147)

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question and add the full error traceback message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the more crisp solution my friend,

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

def scrape_yt(url):
    driver.get(url)
    # scroll the page until it ends
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
    while True:
        # Scroll to the bottom of page
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, arguments[0]);", last_height)
        # Wait for new videos to show up
        time.sleep(1)
        # Calculate new document height and compare it with last height
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height

    time.sleep(2)
    videos = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'ytd-video-renderer')
    print(f"total videos: {len(videos)}")

    links_list = []
    for video in videos:
        link = video.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'h3').find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a').get_attribute('href')
        links_list.append(link)

    return links_list

# ser manual input
search_word = input("Enter the search keyword: ")
url = f"https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query={search_word}"
print(scrape_yt(url))
```

input:

```
Enter the search keyword: GSLV MK3 oneweb
```

output:

```
total videos: 577
['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ruSXQzPJxY8&pp=ygUPR1NMViBNSzMgb25ld2Vi', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=80BhFr3GYag&pp=ygUPR1NMViBNSzMgb25ld2Vi',...., 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FmuVRAojDZY&pp=ygUPR1NMViBNSzMgb25ld2Vi']
```

Hope, it's useful!

Comment: A huge thank you, it works perfectly and it is organised, neat and understandable! Do you have any suggestion on how I can filter out only creators with less then 500 subscribers, exactly from these filtered out links?

Comment: Glad to know that and yes you can filter out the creators of the videos based on their number of subscribers. In the above example, you can extract the creator's channel link in the same way we extracted the video link and then you can go to each creator's channel using that channel link and can extract various details such as the number of videos on their channel and many details including the number of subscribers on their channel.